# JSON from file Swift 3.0 do not work

Tags: json, swift3

I have a problem with JSON, I want to read file JsonData.json using that code(I traied many ways), and always get that error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

Someone can help me?

```
func readPropertyList(){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"JsonData", ofType: "json"){
    //if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"JsonData", withExtension: "json") {
         let url: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            let data: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: url , options: .alwaysMapped)
            //let swiftDictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String]
           //list = swiftDictionary
            let thisJSON = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [] )
            print(thisJSON)
            //print(list)
        } catch {
            print("lol")
        }
    }

}
```

Maybe my, JSON file is wrong but I try verify on http://jsonlint.com and that page say is fine.

```
{

"Eng":
[
    {"Food":
    [
        {"Avilable":true,
        "Meat":
                [
                    {
                    "Meat":"Mięso",
                    "Poultry":"Drób",
                    "Turkey":"Indyk",
                    "Chicken":"Kurczak",
                    "Veal":"Cięcina",
                    "Mutton":"Baranina",
                    "Venison":"Sarnina",
                    "Pork":"Wieprzowina",
                    "Beef":"Wołowina",
                    "Lamb":"Jagnięcina"
                    }
                ],
        "Fish":
                [
                    {
                    "Fish":"ryba",
                    "Sea food":"Owoce morza",
                    "Shrimps":"Krewetki",
                    "Prawns":"Krewetki",
                    "Mussels":"Małże",
                    "Crayfish":"Rak słodkowodny",
                    "Lobster":"Homar",
                    "Crab":"Krab",
                    "Tuna":"Tuńczyk",
                    "Crap":"Karp",
                    "Eel":"W\u0119gorz",
                    "Sardine":"Sardynka",
                    "Salmon":"\u0141oso\u015b",
                    "Herring":"\u015aled\u017a",
                    "Cod":"Dorsz",
                    "Trout":"Pstr\u0105g",
                    "Bass":"Oko\u0144",
                    "Fl\u0105dra":"Plaice",
                    "Pike":"Szczupak"
                    }
                ],
        "Dairy":
                [
                    {
                    "Dairy":"Nabia\u0142",
                    "Dairy products":"Produkty mleczne",
                    "Milk":"Mleko",
                    "Cheese":"Ser",
                    "Cheeses":"Serki",
                    "Cottage cheese":"Twar\u00f3g",
                    "Cream":"\u015amierana",
                    "Yoghurt":"Jogurt",
                    "Butter":"Mas\u0142o",
                    "Margarine":"Margaryna"
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong API. It's the other way round

```
let thisJSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [] )
```